# e.prevent default - Why do I still launch my form?

Tags: javascript, forms

I have this form and this JS :

form :

```
<form action="" method="">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
          <label for="pass">Mot de passe</label>
          <input type="password" id="pass" name="password" />
          <input type="submit" value="Se connecter" />
```

JS :

```
submitButton.addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const form = e.currentTarget;
  const data = new FormData(form);
  const email = data.get("email");
  const password = data.get("password");

  let user = {
    email: email,
    password: password,
  };
  let response = await fetch("http://localhost:5678/api/users/login", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(user),
  });

  const responseBody = await response.json();
  const token = responseBody.token;
  const id = responseBody.userId;
  const responseHtml = response.status;

  if (responseHtml != 200) {
    alert("Error " + responseHtml + " : Email ou Mot de passe Incorrect");
  } else {
    console.log(responseHtml);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("token", token);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("id", id);
    window.location.replace("./homepage_edit.html");
  }
});
```

With my `e.prevent` in the beginning of my addEvent default and when I use correct password and email I can access to my ./homepage_edit.html.

If it uses wrong email and password I'll get my alert.

BUT, If I don't use `e.preventDefault()`, it will juste reload the page.

For me, `e.preventDefault()`, should prevent to launch the ./homepage_edit.html or the alert message because it will prevent the form to launch the form.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is this submitButton give me the declaration of this variable

Comment: The problem I am expecting here is, you shouldn't register the submit event on a button. Instead give an id to this form and register a submit event on the form it self. Also remove this `action=""` and `method=""` from your form.

If there is a button present inside your form that doesn't require any event registration, submit event will be caught on form not on button

Comment: I think your code is correct.
The `e.preventDefault` will stop the default submit event from happening, in this case reload the page and will continue to execute all the following code within your event handler.

Comment: @PiyushPranjal regarding your comments 9 I changed it for const formLogin = document.querySelector("form")

Comment: @RichardKotze I don't get the logic. I stop de submit but it'll continu to read my function until the if/else?

Comment: @NocerGal fundamentally there are two ways to process form data clientside what you are doing now or on the server. If you did not use preventDefult then the form data will be sent to the server and you can run a similar code as you have now to process the user login details. This will be a secure way of processing sensitive information.

Comment: @RichardKotze I understand it, e.preventDefault will be useful if, for exemple, an user do not respond a password format. But in my case the password and email are correct and respects the format. Sorry I I didn't understand your point...

Comment: I probably don't understand your question and what behaviour you are expecting. But preventDefault won't stop the alert or going to homepage_edit as it's not designed for that.

Comment: @RichardKotze thanks Richard, after reading your comments few times + two videos on YT I finally get what I didn’t understand about prevedefaut. Thanks to have take time to explain me :)

Answer (score 2):

```html
<form id="my-form">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
          <label for="pass">Mot de passe</label>
          <input type="password" id="pass" name="password" />
          <input type="submit" value="Se connecter" />
</form>
```

```
const form = document.querySelector("#my-form");

form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    // Clicking any button present inside your form with type="submit"
    // will trigger this function
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Register an event on **form** not on **button** present inside it

[MDN Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event)

```
Note that the submit event fires on the <form> element itself, and not on any <button> or <input type="submit"> inside it
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I changed it,  but I still have the same issue. I only get error 404 or can connect when I put an e.preventDefault() at the beginning of my function. If I'm not wrong, it's supposed to work without :/